# android multiple markers at this line

Tags: android, error-handling

the following line of code gives me the above error

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NotNull MotionEvent ev)
```

It says "NotNull cannot be reserved to a type"
and
"Overides android.view.View.OnTouchEvent"

Im pretty new to this and havent got a clue what is going on with it

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

mark

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of "@NotNull"? leave it like this: `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` and see if it solves it. If it's not that, I think we need more information, more code or something else.

Comment: thanks seems to do the trick

Comment: Great!, I posted it as answer so you can select it as answered. And also gave more information ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably trying to use `@NotNull` as a type. Remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "@NotNull" part. Leave it has **`public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`**.

*"Multiple markers at this line"* means there are multiple errors, in this case two: *"NotNull cannot be reserved to a type"* and *"Overrides android.view.View.OnTouchEvent"*.

I think the **NotNull cannot be reserved to a type** is because it tries to use a class named NotNull, that does not exist.

**Overrides android.view.View.OnTouchEvent** means the method you are implementing is overriding that one, that means it has to be equivalent, that's why, even if the class `NotNull` did exist, it wouldn't work, because it has to be: `public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)`, as defined by Android ([https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)).